# How to check if object structure exists?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Lets say I parse a JSON object from a 3rd party source:

```
var myObject = {
  person_list: [
    { black_hair: {
      list: [
        'bob',
        'john',
        'allen'
      ]}
    }
  ]
};
```

But if the structure suddenly changes or perhaps the data response was corrupt, how can I check the existence of the in depth parts of the structure?

I can do

```
if ( myObject.person_list.black_hair.list !== undefined ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

But maybe `black_hair` doesn't exist in some cases. If it's missing from the object, then I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined`. So the only way I can think of to check if the entire structure is complete is to check if each level is defined:

```
if ( myObject.person_list !== undefined ) {
  if ( myObject.person_list.black_hair !== undefined ) {
    if ( myObject.person_list.black_hair.list !== undefined ) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

But that is a little bit ridiculous. Is there a simple way to handle this in JavaScript? Is a try, catch the best approach?

Comment: did you tried this `if(myObject && myObject.peson_list && myObject.peson_list.black_hair && myObject.peson_list.black_hair.list){}`

Comment: Could you use jQuery.extend() to create a base-level object? The values might be empty but at least they wouldn't be undefined. It would depend on how large you're expecting myObject to be

Comment: Actually you don't expect the structure to be broken. So I'd say this is a model case for when to use a `try-catch` statement. Otherwise you'd check for way too many things and probably you overlook something. Like what if `person_list` isn't `undefined` but `null`?

Comment: The question is flawed in that the given structure of `myObject.person_list.black_hair.list` is undefined anyway, since `black_hair` is not a property of `person_list`. but rather a property of the object which is the first element in the `person_list` array, so the actual "structure" of this object is `myObject.person_list[0].black_hair.list` so answers given so far would correctly yield `false` if testing for the structure of `myObject.person_list.black_hair.list`

Comment: @chiliNUT good point! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could define a function to check the full structure for you:

```
function defined_structure(obj, attrs) {

    var tmp = obj;

    for(i=0; i<attrs.length; ++i) {
        if(tmp[attrs[i]] == undefined)
            return false;
        tmp = tmp[attrs[i]];
    }

    return true;
}

//...

if(defined_structure(myObject, ['person_list', 0, 'black_hair', 'list']) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

The first parameter is the object with structure to be checked, and the second one is an array with the name of the nested properties.

**Update:**

As pointed out by @chiliNUT, `person_list` is an array. Anyway, this approach works by adding the index of the item you want to check (i.e. `['person_list', 0, 'black_hair', 'list']`).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function I wrote to check whether the property is set. You just need to pass the path to the property as a string.

```
// Check if nested object properties exist on unlimited levels
// param: str 'obj.property.property'
function isset (property)
{
    // split path to object property
    var properties = property.split('.');
    var obj = this;

    //loop through each portion of the path checking if it exists
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
    {
        var current_property = properties[i];
        var next_property = i < properties.length - 1 ? true : false;

        // IF current property exists then we need to check the next level
        if (obj[current_property] !== null && typeof obj[current_property] === 'object' && next_property)
        {
            obj = obj[current_property];
            continue;
        }
        return obj.hasOwnProperty(current_property);
    }
}

if ( isset('myObject.person_list.black_hair.list')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just a bit better way with *meta* object which maps the expected format

```
var meta = {
    name: "person_list",
    type: [],
    component: [{
        name: 'black_hair',
        type: {},
        component: {
            name: 'list',
            type: []
        }
    }]
};

var myObject = {
    person_list: [{
        asdfa: {
            list: [
                'bob',
                'john',
                'allen']
        }
    }]
};

function defined(meta, obj) {
    if (meta.name == 'list' && obj[meta.name] && obj[meta.name].length) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!obj[meta.name]) {
        return false;
    };
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(meta.type) === '[object Array]' && !obj[meta.name].length) {
        return false;
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(meta.type) === '[object Array]' && obj[meta.name].length) {
        for (index in obj[meta.name]) {
            return defined(meta.component[index], obj[meta.name][index]);
        }
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(meta.type) === '[object Object]') {
        return defined(meta.component, obj[meta.name]);
    }
}

console.log(defined(meta, myObject));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/qopipiji/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
if ( myObject?.person_list?.black_hair?.list !== undefined ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

You can refer [this : Optional chaining](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining)